# How would I be able to print out the values of a Fact in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

I have the following Prolog rule that allows the user to input three values and assert a Fact from those values:

```
input(X,Y,Z) :- Fact = ves(X,Y,Z), assertz(Fact).
```

How would I now be able to print out the values of the 'ves' Fact?
I tried this, however I receive a singleton error for X,Y and Z. I would like the 'checkCap' rule to print the values of 'ves'.

```
checkCap :- writeln(ves(X,Y,Z)).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this helps:

```
checkCap :-
    ves(X,Y,Z),          % look up dynamic database
    write(ves(X,Y,Z)),   % write out term
    nl.
```